# Ember.js input focus lost on valueBinding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js

I'm creating application with ember.js + Rails

Here is my `templates/application.emblem`:

```
#wrapper
  article.new
    = view Ember.TextField valueBinding='newPostName'
```

the problem is, that after clicking on input, and pressing any key, **focus on that input is lost**.

It happens only first time and I wonder why. After clicking again, I can type any string and everything works fine.

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '~> 1.13.5'
gem 'ember-emblem-template'
gem 'emblem-source'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research, I found a solution:
    = input value=newPostName

**Explanation:**

First problem is, that valueBinding is deprecated. so:

```
#wrong
= view Ember.TextField valueBinding='newPostName'

#better but still wrong
= view Ember.TextField value=newPostName
```

Note, there are *no quotes* there.

The other problem with this code is, that current `ember` version not uses `view Ember.TextField`so

```
#better but still wrong
= view Ember.TextField value=newPostName

#good enough
= input type='text' value=newPostName
```

but as far as `type='text'` is default for input, there is not required to write it.

```
#excellent
= input value=newPostName
```

Much better.